# Is it possible to access LocalStorage from App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, local-storage

I have an App Script project that uses some config settings. These settings are set in an html service box so they are reflected in LocalStorage and (via google.script.run) in UserProperties.

On start up, the UserProperties appear to be reset so is there a way I can access LocalStorage to get around this and retrieve the correct settings from a previous session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side code on Apps SCript can't access [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) on the user web browser as it runs on the Google Servers. You should use client side code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Rubén. What do you suggest to use instead? I'm at a loss on how to maintain and access user settings if UserProperties seems to reset at startup

Comment: @JoshM It looks that you don't know what is resetting the UserProperties. IMHO you should check your code to figure up that. Create a [mcve] and if you still needs help post a new question.